# Flutter: JsonUnsupportedObjectError (Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'DateTime')

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

i want to convert the object to string to store in local device using sharedpreference. there was error to convert List to string in json . this is the code

```
static String encode(List<Rows>? obj) => json.encode(
        musics!
            .map<Map<String, dynamic>>((music) => Rows.toMap(music))
            .toList(),
      );
```

this is the code i got from another example sharedpreference here, i thought it supposed to work to all kind of data type. how to solve this?

this is model i worked on

```
class Rows {
  String? id;
  DateTime? dateoflastinsp;
  DateTime? dateofinsp;
  String? inspby;

  Rows({this.id, this.dateoflastinsp, this.dateofinsp, this.inspby});

  Rows.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    dateoflastinsp = json['dateoflastinsp'] == null
          ? null
          : DateTime.parse(json['dateoflastinsp'] as String);
    dateofinsp = json['dateofinsp'] == null
          ? null
          : DateTime.parse(json['dateofinsp'] as String);
    inspby = json['inspby'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['id'] = id;
    data['dateoflastinsp'] = dateoflastinsp;
    data['dateofinsp'] = dateofinsp;
    data['inspby'] = inspby;
    return data;
  }

  static Map<String, dynamic> toMap(Rows music) => {
        'dateofinsp': music.dateofinsp,
        'dateoflastinsp': music.dateoflastinsp,
        'id': music.id, 
        'inspby': music.inspby, 
      };
}
```